# Close subform, remove main form filter and go back to original record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am opening a subform from my main form to allow data to be changed.  Once the changes are made, I want to pass the data back to the main form. remove the filter, and go back to the original record.  I have the Primary Key in the subform so I am passing it back.  I used some code from another user's but it did not work not is my code.  Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub cmd_close_Click()
Dim result As String
Dim ID As Variant

result = MsgBox("Save Geo Location?", vbOKCancel, "Save Geo Location")

If result = vbOK Then
    Forms!frm_acct_select!GeoLoc_X = Me.txt_GeoLocX
    Forms!frm_acct_select!GeoLoc_Y = Me.txt_GeoLocY
    Forms!frm_acct_select.FilterOn = False
 
'this code fails immediately
    With frm_acct_select.Form
    ID = Me.txt_ParentID.Value
    .FilterOn = False
    .Recordset.FindFirst "ParentAccountID=" & ID
    End With

'this code fails type mismatch criteria at the recordset.findfirst line
'        With Forms!frm_acct_select
'          ID = Me.txt_ParentID.Value
'          .FilterOn = False
'          .Recordset.FindFirst "ParentAccountID = " & ID
'        End With
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "sfrm_geoloc_update", acSaveNo
Else
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "sfrm_acct_select_search", acSaveNo
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_? I see no SQL, and no table data.

Comment: Not sure how I references SQL.

Comment: {56D0791E-0B1B-4955-818A-97CBA4291B32} is the value of the ID.  I tried specifying Variant as was in the original code and also declaring String. Both variations failed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I still need to work on my string formatting.
Declaring ID as String was correct however I needed to add quotes to my code.

```
.Recordset.FindFirst "ParentAccountID = '" & ID & "'"
```